# Can I mix OpenGL and swing?

Tags: opengl, java

I'm working on a small game library for me and some people I know that just handles the window and nothing special that we weren't gonna use. I know how to use OpenGL and stuff I just don't like having to deal with more then one library at a time like OpenGL and Swing so I want to combine them into something basic. Anyway my question is, is there any way I can use OpenGL's rendering onto Swing? I need a simple answer. I also don't want to have to include other libraries into my library, I just want it to be the only jar in the program that isn't program specific.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [JOGL (Java™ Binding for the OpenGL® API)](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) allows exactly that. See also [this post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/campbell/archive/2005/09/java2djogl_inte_1.html) for more information about OpenGL and Swing interoperability. Also see XTrans demo on JOGL [demos](https://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/www/) page.

Mixing Swing and OpenGL has a little performance penalty though, so you should consider other options if realtime 3D is your primary feature and Swing is just a small user interface in the game.

Comment: Can I pack everything into 1 jar so it contains all the OpenGL stuff when I build it?

Comment: Yes, at least everything except the native binaries (.dll files on Windows)

Comment: @msell Are JOGL and [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) equivalent? JOGL is external library. Is there any solution built into JDK for this?

Comment: @iamcreasy No they are not equivalent. No there is no built in OpenGL API in JDK.